# Subtract each row in table 2 from the count result of table 1

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Basically I have two query outputs :

First query gives the total count :

```
select COUNT(*) as 'TotalStudents' from StudentLists
```

This gives an output of count  let say 50.

Second query :

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP(week_date date,cused int)
insert into #TMP(cused ,week_date)
select *  
from
(select studentid, clientdate
  from table1 where DATEDIFF(DAY,clientdate,GETDATE()) <= 7
  union 
  select studentid, DATE
  from table2 where DATEDIFF(DAY,DATE,GETDATE()) <= 7 
 ) a 

 select week_date ,COUNT(distinct cused )as 'Totalcused ' from #TMP 
 group by week_date
```

Second query gives me the output as :

```
week_date   Totalcused 
2013-07-18  11
 2013-07-19 18
2013-07-20  23
2013-07-22  9
2013-07-23  19
```

Now, I want to subtract each row cused with totalstudents in query1.

My expected output should be ,

```
week_date   Totalcused nused
2013-07-18  11        39
 2013-07-19 18        32
2013-07-20  23        27
2013-07-22  9         41
2013-07-23  19        31
```

How can I incorporate first query result into this query :

```
 select week_date ,COUNT(distinct cused )as 'Totalcused ' from #TMP 
 group by week_date
```

to get the above output.
There is no common column name to joins these first and second queries.

First query output value will be keep changing every day, the output is not a constant value all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the Total to a variable, and use that in the second query.

Something like

```
DECLARE @Total INT

select @Total = COUNT(*) from StudentLists 

CREATE TABLE #TMP(week_date date,cused int)
insert into #TMP(cused ,week_date)
select *  
from
(select studentid, clientdate
  from table1 where DATEDIFF(DAY,clientdate,GETDATE()) <= 7
  union 
  select studentid, DATE
  from table2 where DATEDIFF(DAY,DATE,GETDATE()) <= 7 
 ) a 

 select week_date ,
        COUNT(distinct cused )as 'Totalcused ', 
        @Total - COUNT(distinct cused ) as 'nused'  
 from #TMP 
 group by week_date
```

Comment: And if you were to run the query every day, the results would change. Are you looking to store the values in a table, and hope they change every day?